# Custom Condition for Marketing Automation Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: contact-facets, automation

**Hi**

I'm working on a custom condition which I want to put on a marketing campaign inside of the marketing automation. I created the below and added it to the marketing automation campaign and  it runs OK but the problem I have is that the Contact facet is **missing the TestFacet** (I checked the Xdb and the testfacet data is there). so when I do GetFacet it comes back as NULL.

Also when I check the facet via the website rather than automation engine I'm able to add/edit it no problem, so its just not showing in the automation engine for me.

```
public class EmailPermissionRule : ICondition, IMappableRuleEntity
{
    public virtual bool Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
    {
        var contact = context.Fact<Contact>();

        var testFacet = contact.GetFacet<TestFacet>(TestFacet.DefaultFacetKey);

        return testFacet?.permission != null && testFacet.permission == true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: for any reason, do you think you need to create a segmented list? you have not implemented IContactSearchQueryContext here.

Comment: not sure if i need to create a segmented list? Would me adding IContactSearchQueryContext bring in the custom facet that is missing in the contact facet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you:

1. Deploy **json** model with your facet to **"xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Models"** folder.
2. Deploy **dll** with facet implementation to **"xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine"** folder.
3. Add your facet to contact loader in **"xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\config\sitecore\MarketingAutomation\sc.MarketingAutomation.ContactLoader.xml"** (or add it with patch):

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <XConnect>
      <MarketingAutomation>
        <Engine>
          <Services>
            <!-- Include or exclude contact facets for the contact during loading -->
            <MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
              <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator, Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation</Type>
              <As>Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Core.Loading.IContactExpandOptionsConfigurator, Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Core</As>
              <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
              <Options>
                <IncludeFacetNames>
                  <Addresses>Addresses</Addresses>
                  <ConsentInformation>ConsentInformation</ConsentInformation>
                  <Emails>Emails</Emails>
                  <EngagementMeasures>EngagementMeasures</EngagementMeasures>
                  <ListSubscriptions>ListSubscriptions</ListSubscriptions>
                  <Personal>Personal</Personal>
                  <TestFacet>TestFacet</TestFacet> // <---- HERE ----
                  <InteractionsCache>InteractionsCache</InteractionsCache>
                </IncludeFacetNames>
              </Options>
             ...
            </MarketingAutomation.Loading.ContactFacetsConfigurator>
          </Services>
        </Engine>
      </MarketingAutomation>
    </XConnect>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Comment: Yes!! adding the facet to contact loader worked! Thanks man been trying to figure it out for days :D